# How to make my cellphone a router or a hotspot thing with a constraint

Tags: wi-fi, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

My computer is connected to internet but I dont have a router(and I dont want to buy one) to use it on my phone. So I was using the usb "reverse tethering tool" which i could use succesfully.

But now I want to use my phone as a router so that I can connect to internet from anywhere in my room with other phones.

And yes I dont want to buy a router, My PC doesnt have a wifi or bluetooth connectivity.

Thankyou for your time.

Sincerely,

Jasser

I am using samsung galaxy S duos GT-S7562.

Comment: Interesting quedtion. I upvoted it. Even i had the same doubt

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by turning on *Portable Wi-Fi hotspot*.

Go to *Settings* -> *More Settings* under *Wireless and Networks* -> *Tethering and Portable Hotspot* and turn *Portable Wi-Fi hotspot* on.

[image: settings]
[image: More Setings]
[image: Tethering and Portable Wi-Fi hotspot]

After turning it on click on it to configure your connection, where you can change the hotspot's name and password.

[image: configuration]

But the devices you connect with this phone must have a Wi-Fi adapter and the necessary software. Or else they won't be able to connect.

Also consider changing the security settings incase you are not able to connect, because when I tried it on my phone, I had to turn off security (you will find it in the configuration screen).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The security settings doesnt help either. @Switch I also tried the bluetooth tethering but it also did not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn your device into a Wifi Hotspot (there is an option in the general settings, usually with the other connectivity settings).

Generally, you will need to pay your Cellphone provider to allow you to use this particular feature (although there are ways to get around this - but that is another thread).

Bottom line, there is an option in the settings - if your phone can support this, you will easily be able to turn it on.

Comment: When I use reverse tethering I am not able to use wifihot-spot.... I have already tried that.....

Comment: I mean it shows the sign of hotspot and I am able to connect one phone with another but i am not able to get internet access @booger

Comment: You likely don't have that service enabled from your cell phone provider.  That is specifically what I am saying.

Comment: Yes it does but the problem is that it is not working when I do it with reverse tethering part @Booger